# I'm getting "No module named 'Rosetta3'" error while im trying to run the script in Spyder as standalone installer

Tags: python, github, anaconda, spyder

[image]

I tried `pip install` in command prompt, I have added environment variables but still I'm getting the same issue, kindly assist.

Rosetta3 is a pedo transfer function tool which helps to determine soil retention parameters.

Comment: do you use python environments? the environment you have rosetta installed to may not be the default environment

Comment: Yes i use python environments and i have added rosetta3 in the environment variable as well

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Seems like you are using the Spyder standalone version. To install packages outside the ones that come with the installer you need to config have a way to create python environments and then set the Python interpreter preference on Spyder to point to the correct environment. For more info you can check the Spyder docs FAQ page: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer

Comment: @Daniel Althviz, thank you i shall try and see if it works

Comment: @Chris Sure, thanks  ill take care of it.